# what is the right syntax for watch command

Tags: watch

I want to follow the word BLOCK in ufw.log file every two seconds

I try this command:

```
sudo watch BLOCK /var/log/ufw.log
```

but I getting: sh: 1: BLOCK: not found

what is the right command?

Thank You

---

Edit

Following this command tail -f /var/log/ufw.log | grep BLOCK This is the output:

```
[ 6951.750905] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=xxxx SRC=88.99.100.01 DST=180.20.40.11 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=110 ID=26663 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59501 DPT=21 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

How to filter the output to show only the SRC=«ip_address»

So that the output will be only: `SRC=88.99.100.01`

Comment: Maybe you could tell us what you *expect* the `watch` command to do there, because a quick look at the manpage suggests it does something entirely different than what you're probably expecting.

Comment: i want to look this file: ufw.log every two seconds, and when a new line with the word BLOCK created display on the screen

Comment: Try `tail -f /var/log/ufw.log | grep BLOCK`

Comment: @Shadur's suggestion is the way to go. You may also need to pass `--line-buffered` to `grep` to suppress output buffering

Comment: `tail -f …` is better, but what you were trying to do was `sudo watch grep BLOCK /var/log/ufw.log`. You missed out the command, `watch` takes a command.

Comment: Try `tail -F /var/log/ufw.log | sed -n -e '/BLOCK/ {s/.*\(SRC=[^ ]*\).*/\1/p}'`.   Using `-F` instead of `-f` tells `tail` to not only follow the log, but to re-open the tailed filename if it gets rotated (i.e. closed, renamed, and replaced).

Answer (score 3):

From the `watch` manpage:

## WATCH(1)

### NAME

```
   watch - execute a program periodically, showing output fullscreen
```

### SYNOPSIS

```
   watch [options] command
```

### DESCRIPTION

`watch` runs  `command`  repeatedly, displaying its output and errors (the first screenfull). This allows you to watch the program output change over time.

By default, the program is run every 2 seconds.

By default, `watch` will run until interrupted.

---

This does not seem to fit at all with whatever you think it may do given the command line you're using. You may be looking for an entirely different command...

**EDIT:** As per what you added in the comments, what you want *could* be done with `watch`, but it's the wrong tool for the job.

`tail -f /var/log/ufw.log | grep BLOCK` will continually follow the logfile, but only print lines containing 'BLOCK' to the screen, which is closer to what I suspect you want.